# Embedding and compactness of thickened family of graphs

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $\{G_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ be a family of graphs $G_n=(V_n,E_n)$ for which $|V_n|$ and $|E_n|$ tend to infinity. I would like to know if the family of objects $\{M_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ obtained by thickening (in some dimension) each $G_n$, such that $M_n$ all have bounded curvature, is a family of well defined compact manifolds, no matter the dimension of the thickening.

The idea I have in mind is the following:  if $\{G_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ is a family of graphs that cannot be locally embedded in $\mathbb{R}^l$ (for example a tree graph, or an expandre graphs, cannot be locally embed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e if we require nodes to be all spaced by a distance greater than some constant, the edge length do not have an upper bound) and we construct a thickening of $\{G_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ (with bounded curvature) where the thickening are $l/2-$ dimensional handles, wouldn't this contradict some embedding theorem such as Whitney embedding theorem.

It seems that there is a notion of "blowing up" that would complicate the embedding, such as the hyperbolic plane which is "too big" to be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Another related question: if we construct a family of graph that are locally embedded in $\mathbb{H}^2$ but not $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we thickened this graph with $3D$-handles to construct $\{M_n\}_\mathbb{N}$, is $\{M_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ a well defined family of compact manifolds with bounded curvature and with embedding in $\mathbb{R^3}$ ?

Comment: Nash embedding doesn't say anything on large scale ambient distances, I don't think there's a contradiction here

Comment: What about compactness ?